# Bitcoin-based Distributed Donation Systems, whichs do you know?

Tags: tor, open-source, donation, wealth-distribution

I've heard that [Tor Project](https://www.torproject.org/) constructed such system:

- Everybody who are participating in the Tor Network, creating *Exit Node* or even *Middle Node*, would simply paste his *Bitcoin address* into the **"Nickname" field**.
- All donates are clearly transparent and divides by the fair mechanism.

---

Now, I'm thinking, How is really great this Experiment.

And wondering, such mechanism with only one address to Donate and available [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/) would give fair Donation to any open-source project. For example `Linux Kernel Developers` or other GNU projects would simply install such daemon/system by similar `# apt-get install` command.

Github information would give percentage of job for each person, daemon will split Bitcoin input according to this data and it will be fair and easy controllable by blockchain.info's data.

---

Thereafter, I'm wondering, Is there anything else, except Tor Project.

I'm meaning "Global", Distributed, Bitcoin-based Donation System. Not only for closely-knitted group, where one person taking all donations and as a General commanding to his army who gonna getting what.

Probably such list will be good adding to bitcoin wiki and this site too.